# Differential equation of the form to find

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Lets $f(z)$ is some analytic function on complex plane and $y(z)$ is known analytic function on complex plane. 
Problem statement: find all $f(z)$ that: $$f(z) = f(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z})y(z)$$

For example:

If $y(z) = z$, then $f(z) = z$.

If $y(z) = \exp(z)$, then $f(z) = \exp(cz)$, where $c = \exp(c)$

Is there any general method to find $f(z)$ based on $y(z)$?
What would be $f(z)$ if $y(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$

Comment: sorry, what is the meaning of $f(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z})$?

Comment: @wisefool, if $f$ is analytic function, it can be expressed as convergent power series of $z$. Then replace each $z$ with $z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

Comment: so, if, for instance $f(z)=z^2$, then $f(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=z\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + z^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.